# Using MinimalBy to find list with smallest sum of absolute values

Tags: filtering

I have a list of lists:

```
val={{-8, -8, 1, 1}, {-8, -7, -4, 5}, {-8, -2, 8, -6}, {-8, -1, 
  3, -2}, {-8, 1, -7, 6}, {-8, 6, 5, -5}, {-8, 8, -5, 3}, {-6, -5, 
  5, -3}, {-6, -3, -5, 5}, {-6, 2, 7, -6}, {-6, 3, 2, -2}, {-6, 4, -3,
   2}, {-6, 5, -8, 6}, {-4, -7, -3, 4}, {-4, -6, -8, 8}, {-4, -1, 
  4, -3}, {-4, 1, -6, 5}, {-4, 6, 6, -6}, {-4, 7, 1, -2}, {-4, 8, -4, 
  2}, {-2, -5, 6, -4}, {-2, -3, -4, 4}, {-2, 2, 8, -7}, {-2, 3, 
  3, -3}, {-2, 4, -2, 1}, {-2, 5, -7, 5}, {2, -5, 7, -5}, {2, -4, 
  2, -1}, {2, -3, -3, 3}, {2, -2, -8, 7}, {2, 3, 4, -4}, {2, 5, -6, 
  4}, {4, -8, 4, -2}, {4, -7, -1, 2}, {4, -6, -6, 6}, {4, -1, 
  6, -5}, {4, 1, -4, 3}, {4, 6, 8, -8}, {4, 7, 3, -4}, {6, -5, 
  8, -6}, {6, -4, 3, -2}, {6, -3, -2, 2}, {6, -2, -7, 6}, {6, 3, 
  5, -5}, {6, 5, -5, 3}, {8, -8, 5, -3}, {8, -6, -5, 5}, {8, -1, 
  7, -6}, {8, 1, -3, 2}, {8, 2, -8, 6}, {8, 7, 4, -5}, {8, 8, -1, -1}}
```

And I want to find the list for which the sum of the absolute values of its elements is the smallest.  I.e., if we represent each list as {a,b,c,d}, then I want to find the one for which |a|+|b|+|c|+|d| is smallest.  If there's more than one, then I only need one of them.

I can obtain this as follows:

```
vtot = Total /@ Abs@val; val[[Position[vtot, Min@vtot][[1, 1]]]]
```

> {-2, 4, -2, 1}

However, I was wondering if this could be done more cleanly using `MinimalBy`.

The following doesn't work:

```
First@MinimalBy[val, Abs]
```

> {-2, 2, 8, -7}

Comment: You need `First @ MinimalBy[val, Total @* Abs]`.

Comment: Got it, thanks @LeonidShifrin

Comment: Also, `First@MinimalBy[val, Norm[#, 1] &]`